# How to fix WebService and package-info.java in oracle weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, weblogic, weblogic12c

i am making web service using Java EE6 when i deploy on oracle web-logic version 12c its working fine but on web service response i want to do some customization related to namespace so i make package-info.java file like below

---

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.simple.org/",
attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package example;
```

---

basically i need this package every tag should be qualified but there is no different after add this file and result as same so somebody can help how i can fixed this issue on oracle weblogic?

by the way when i deploy on glassfish 3 its working fine mean there is something thing related to oracle weblogic.

Comment: i do something more investigation and found this bug on oracle Weblogic 12c because i deploy same application on 11g and it also working fine like glassfish 3

Answer (score 0):

We had hit the exact same problem 2 days ago. The solution in our case was removing all method-level annotations from the service implementation class, and specifying the fully qualified name of the interface in the @WebService annotation in the endpointInterface attribute.

Example:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(name = "...", portName = "...", serviceName = "...", targetNamespace = "http://..", endpointInterface = "...")
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
...
}
```

(we needed the @Stateless annotation as well as the webservice was packaged in the backend ear file).

An alternativ method which worked for us was making the webservice implementation class not implementing the service interface (practically breaking the connection between the two) and copying all annotations to the implementation class.